# Move to specific record in Access on Form_Open using OpenArgs

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

So I have a Form opening and on the Form_Open event the following runs.

```
If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
    With Me.RecordsetClone
        .FindFirst "Ref=" & Me.OpenArgs
        If Not .NoMatch Then
            Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
        End If
    End With
End If
```

Howver I get run time error 3021 - 'No current record'. Hitting debug indicates error is on the Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark line, and if I press F5 the code continues to run and completes as expected! Any ideas?
I have searched for a solution, and many people suggest using a filter, but I already have a filter selecting a range of records applied which I need to retain.

Comment: Try put the same code in the Form_Load event.